# why are there many possible duplicates for a question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

if a question is down voted for the reason that there are possible duplicates of it . then why are there more than one duplicate for a question , why are not the other duplicates deleted / rejected  by Admin.

Comment: Downvotes are not tied with the fact that question is a duplicate. Also, sometimes question is so broad or so unclear voters can't decide which of the older ones answers it better, but are pretty sure that answer is already there. **This does not mean that older ones are duplicates of each other**.

Comment: @Molot then why was i down voted badly for this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218146/if-someone-downvotes-a-question-why-is-the-op-not-provided-with-details-of-what

Comment: Because your duplicate lacks any real content? Because the way you asked it is basically unanswerable, as we can't see into heads of all downvoters? Because you appear not to know about any of the previous attempts to discuss that topic, and there was so many it's hardly possible to fail to find one, if you would really search for them?

Comment: @Constantine - Due to thousands of duplicate(and no new point), Bad formatting, no proper tag (same here).

Comment: Please [read this manual about Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188/225745), @Constantine. It'll make your life here smoother.

Comment: @Constantine That duplicate comes under "However, obvious duplicates are often downvoted. Especially if the duplicate is asked a lot because this shows no research was done before asking."

Answer (score 6):

### Duplicates can be useful

There is more than one way to phrase a question, as such duplicates can be helpful in allowing different search terms to lead to the same answers. However, splitting answers between them dilutes answers making finding/judging the best answers more difficult. This is why they are not deleted but just closed.

### Why are duplicates downvoted?

I would say that they are not, sometimes known duplicates are even upvoted when well written. However, obvious duplicates are often downvoted. Especially if the duplicate is asked **a lot** because this shows no research was done before asking.